# How use cut/awk/sed command to select as records from a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, cut

I have a file (details.txt) with content in below format.

```
Serial Number: 0xf
Name: XXX
Age: 25
Sex: Male
Serial Number: 0xe
Name: YYY
Age: 27
Sex: FeMale
```

I want to retrieve **complete record** of a person with Name say "XXX".

How can it be achieved with **cut** command?

Comment: If at all, definitely not easily.  Why are you constrained to cut?  Why not use awk?

Comment: what do you want to do with the `complete record` ?

Comment: My script should not  return age of YYY when I ask for XXX. Parameter I ask and get will differ at runtime.

Comment: Post the expected output to go with your sample input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use grep like this:

```
grep -B1 -A2 "Name: XXX"
```

-B1 and -A2 mean that grep should also print one line before and two lines after the match.

Comment: Thats a fantastic answer! Works like charm.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=": *"; OFS=": "; split(tgt,a); tgtTag=a[1]; tgtVal=a[2] }
{ tags[++numTags] = $1; tag2val[$1] = $2 }
numTags == 4 {
    if (tag2val[tgtTag] == tgtVal) {
        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            print tag, tag2val[tag]
        }
    }
    numTags = 0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v tgt="Name:XXX" -f tst.awk file
Serial Number: 0xf
Name: XXX
Age: 25
Sex: Male

$ awk -v tgt="Age:25" -f tst.awk file
Serial Number: 0xf
Name: XXX
Age: 25
Sex: Male

$ awk -v tgt="Age:27" -f tst.awk file
Serial Number: 0xe
Name: YYY
Age: 27
Sex: FeMale

$ awk -v tgt="Sex:FeMale" -f tst.awk file
Serial Number: 0xe
Name: YYY
Age: 27
Sex: FeMale
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '$!N;/Name: XXX/{N;N;p;}' filename
```

Comment: Will this work if i give "Age:25" as input? The entire record of **0xf** is expected.

Comment: Could you explain this answer?

Comment: @KurinchiMalar: No. Your question was about searching by name, and this extracts the entire record containing `Name: XXX`. Do you want to search by name, or by age, or by serial number, or what?

Comment: @RickSmith: Loosely, it says "don't print everything, keep track of the last line, if you see "Name: XXX" then grab two more lines and print the whole record.

Answer (score 0):

`paste` will allow you to put all the fields for a record on the same line (as long as your entire file is composed records that are each 4 lines).

```
# this will give the age of XXX
paste - - - - < details.txt | grep 'Name: XXX' | cut -f 3 | cut -f 2 -d:
```

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '/^Name: XXX/,/^Serial Number:/ { print }' FILE
```

Will print everything in between `/^Name: XX/` and `/^Serial Number:/` including the

**Output for your FILE:**

```
Name: XXX
Age: 25
Sex: Male
Serial Number: 0xe
```

This absolutely cannot be done with `cut` and you might want to consider languages like `perl`, `ruby` or `python` for this.

Comment: This is not working. I tried **cat details.txt | awk '/^Name: XXX/,/^Serial Number:/ { print }' result.txt**   result.txt is empty

Comment: @KurinchiMalar `awk '/^Name: XXX/,/^Serial Number:/ { print }' details.txt > result.txt`

Comment: What if I give only Age as input? I want the entire record based on no sequential ordering. It should be like selective query.

Comment: Then you need to store the records in a data structure (e.g., a hash). Awk does have hashes. Check http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html .

Comment: Then either use hashes in awk (http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html ) or convert the data to a tabular structure which is much easier to work with in awk.

Comment: Never use range expressions as they make trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then need a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions if the job becomes even the tiniest bit more interesting. Always use a flag instead, e.g. `awk '/start/{f=1} f; /end/{f=0}'`.